# Issue in using VBA for Finite Difference Method

Tags: vba, math, calculus

The question to be done

[image: The question to be done]

I have tried this out.

I have created few functions. I am confused in the remaining ones.

I have made the first function and stored the values of upper, lower and main matrix in my spreadsheet.

```
Function createFEMatrixDirichlet(a, C, Nx, h, dt)
    Dim k As Integer
    'Main
    For k = 0 To Nx - 1
    Cells(k + 2, 2).Value = 1 - dt * (((2 * a) / (h * h)) + x)
    Next k
    'Lower
    For k = 0 To Nx - 2
    Cells(k + 2, 1).Value = dt * (a / (h * h))
    Next k
    'Upper
    For k = 0 To Nx - 3
    Cells(k + 2, 3).Value = dt * (a / (h * h))
    Next k
End Function
```

Nodes are generated similar way.

```
Function nodeGeneration(xa, xb, Nx, column)
    Dim k As Integer
    'Find h
    h = (xb - xa) / Nx
    'Generate Node
    For k = 0 To Nx
    Cells(k + 2, column).Value = xa + k * h
    Next k
End Function
```

Initial condition are applied:

```
Function applyInitialCondition(Nx, column)
    Dim k As Integer
    For k = 0 To Nx
    Cells(k + 2, column).Value = ((Cells(k + 2, 4)) + 2) / 2
    Next k
End Function
```

Now to multiply I am a bit confused. My implementation is that I am trying to make the entire matrix and then multiply. However, there is no luck. Some or the other error pops up.

Also, I have no idea on how to implement the FETimeStep and then create a new subroutine to run the entire code.

Any leads?

Sample Input

[image: Sample Input Here]

Comment: Do you have some example input data and the expected output of that? What is the purpose of that algorithm?

Comment: Yup I have an example input. I will edit the question and write.

Comment: It is an algorithm to solve partial differential equation. The first link contains all the details.